# How to diff disassembled binary files?

Tags: c++, assembly, diff

Sometimes I wonder how a code change will cause the emitted code to change.
I don't know of any easy way to find just what has changed.

What I normally do is going through a diff of the disassembles, such as

```sh
# compile 1.o and 2.o
diff <(objdump -M intel -d 1.o) <(objdump -M intel -d 2.o)
```

but this is super flaky: if the new binary uses other registers (and nothing else changes), the diff will still be substantial. Also, needless to say, it doesn't really understand the structure of assembly, so if independent instructions are reordered, they're still in the diff.

Is there a better way or tool to diff disassembled binary files?

Comment: Which C++ compiler do you use ?

Comment: A `diff` tool doesn't understand the structure of *any* language, it just looks at the lines. What you are looking for is a kind of AST (abstract syntax tree) that would get generated during the compilation of assembly code. But the very purpose of an assembly language is to have as little structure as possible. It's just labels and instructions, where only the order of instructions matters.

Comment: Best is to have the compiler emit assembly code (`-S`) and do a diff on that instead of the object files.

Comment: The real question is: WHY? What and why do you want see in this diff? Are you looking for a tool like https://godbolt.org/ or  https://cppinsights.io/

Comment: You generally have to just analyze the code yourself, diff might tell you where to start looking, but as soon as one instruction or data byte is added or removed the addresses change and then all the lines change.

Comment: compiling to assembly helps in one respect but hurts in others as you are looking at pseudo instructions and other items that are changed as they go into the binary and become real instructions